# Terminate existing tcp connection

Tags: c++

Is there a way to kill off an existing connection??

For example, 192.168.1.120 is connected to be via port 8080.

I would like to know how to terminate that connection?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it a connection from inside your program to something else, or a connection to a server socket in your program, or a completely external connection between other programs?

Comment: @sje397

It's an external connection made by other programs.

Comment: On linux you can use killcx. See my answer to "[How to forcibly close a socket in TIME_WAIT?][1]"

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait/7946580#7946580

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is tagged C++ (and I had the same question), I presume that the OP wanted an example that uses the Windows API. I've done this using the `GetTcpTable2` and `SetTcpEntry` APIs. You'll need to call `GetTcpTable2` and filter the results to the connection you want to terminate, then pass it to `SetTcpEntry`. Note that I took a bit of a shortcut with allocating memory for `GetTcpTable2`, so if you're writing production code, you'll want to read the Microsoft documentation on how best to correctly use the API.

Feel free to use the code I wrote and published under the MIT licence on Github:

- [TcpConnectionKiller.cpp](https://github.com/nzbart/TcpConnectionKiller/blob/master/TcpConnectionKiller/TcpConnectionKiller.cpp)

Comment: Unfortunately this only does ipv4. What function is used for ipv6?

Comment: It looks like there's an equivalent for enumerating the connections (`GetTcp6Table2`), but I can't find an IPv6 equivalent to `SetTcpEntry`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way (without external software) is to kill and/or restart the process that's watching that port.  That'll kill off every connection used by that process, though, so it's not something you normally want to do on a server.

To find out which process is handling the connection on your side, you can say `netstat -anp` in Linux, or `netstat -anb` in Windows.  Note, in Windows, `netstat` can be quite slow in backtracking from a socket to a process.

If you're using Windows, and don't mind downloading something, check out SysInternals' [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx).  Lets you see what ports are open, and what's using them.  It can even kill connections, IIRC, though i forget whether it's by simply resetting the connection or by killing the process using it.